# Lower bounding the binomial summation

Tags: binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

For $n>1$ and $~0<p < 1$,   can we lower bound the following   binomial series in terms of $n$ and $p$ $$\sum_{i=\lceil p n \rceil}^n {n \choose i} (p )^i(1-p)^{(n-i)}.$$

I have posted the question on cs.theroy.stackexchange site, there I came to know that the above can be lower bounded by $$  1/2- \frac C{\sqrt{p(1-p)n}}.$$
due to  [Berry–Esseen theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) (for a certain constant C < 0.5). I just wanted to know if a more tighter lower bound is known for the same.

Sorry for repeating the question here.

Thanks in advance!